# How to hide short-cut popup when using it

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2022.1.4, but after upgrade to 2022.2 shortcut popup is always show and when I'm trying to use IDE terminal will block my typing.

I tried to search it everywhere, but it does not found any results.

[image: file capture]